# How to ask Python if a sensor is activated, BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine

I am a total beginner with python combined with BGE.
I wrote that:

```
import bge


def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    if MessageSensor.positive or MouseSensor.positive:
        MessageActuator.activate

main()
```

it doesn't work, what's wrong?

Comment: To markup script for bse, using blender text editor: select all; hit tab (tabs all one right, the markup for code),; copy; then paste here.  Back in blender, shift tab tabs all back one right.

Comment: "It doesn't work" can mean anything from "it blows up my computer" to "I get this error message" to "nothing at all happens, it's as if my script isn't there". You'll have to be more specific and give actual details about what you expect to happen, why you expect that to happen, and what you're observing.

Comment: @batFINGER to markup code (after it is pasted in the post) select it all and press `ctrl` + `K`.

Comment: I strongly suggest to open the blender console before starting the game. It will show you all errors your code is getting.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly  `MessageSensor & MouseSensor & MessageActuator` are undefined. And the controller is the one how activate de actuator.

```
import bge
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
MessageSensor = cont.sensors['NameOfSensor']
MouseSensor = cont.sensors['NameOfSensor']
MessageActuator = cont.actuators['NameOfActuator']

if MessageSensor.positive or MouseSensor.positive:
    cont.activate(MesageActuator)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the sensors and actuators wrong. Assuming you have mouse senor named "Mouse" (the default name), a message sensor named "Message", and a a message actuator named "Message" all on the same object the corrected code below will work.

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

if cont.sensors['Message'].positive or cont.sensors['Mouse'].positive:
    cont.activate(cont.actuators['Message'])
```

You access the the object that everything is on with `bge.logic.getCurrentController()` then the [sensors](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.sensors), controllers, and actuators are all in their own lists. You simply specify them by name, or position.

You really should look through the Docs for [bge.logic](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.logic.html) (all the logic bricks are in the logic section.)

---

But I have to ask why do you need that? If all you need is to activate an actuator when either senor is true, then just use an *Or* controller.
[image: logic bricks with an or controller]

Comment: It is true that it is possible to do with the elements integrated in the game logic editor, but I'd like to start learning to do things with python to create more complex things later on, so I'd like to use python. But thank you for your answer.