# Blender BGE, Logic or python problem. Always place two elements?

Tags: python, game-engine

I´m messing around with BGE and have some troubles on the way, but it's fun.

The game I'm making is a bomberman like game, i made the logics and scripts so it works and it place the bomb quite fine, but for some reason it always places 2 bombs no matter what, can anyone see what i might have done wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]

YES THATS IT /// SOLUTION IS

I had to change the logic Property (called placebomb) Evaluation Type to "Greater Than" from "Equal To" because the "Equal To" pulse always twice for some reason i can't explain.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is triggered twice. On positive and negative pulse of the sensor.
Check if the sensor triggering the script is positive:
[How to ask Python if a sensor is activated, BGE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96799/how-to-ask-python-if-a-sensor-is-activated-bge)

Comment: You are absolutely right about that :) one step closer. But why is the script trigger on negative pulse xD that don't really make sense to me.

Comment: Its solved, thank you very much :) have nice day